# Google Maps Android v2 - Detecting Marker InfoWindow Close

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Right now I have markers that when clicked, begin autorefreshing the contents of their info windows in the background.

The thing is, once the user closes the info window (like clicking elsewhere on the map), the background task still goes on.

Is there a way to detect when a marker InfoWindow is closed so I can close the task then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have a single `InfoWindow` open at a time, which means you can track the one that's open:

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Info window requested for " + marker);
        mLastMarker = marker;
        return null; // Returning null will load the default InfoWindow
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

Now on each map click you can check if the task on a specific marker is still running:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        if (mLastMarker != null) {
            mLastMarker = null;
            // Stop task
        }
    }
});
```

If you want, you can also stop the tasks when changing the `InfoWindow`:

```
@Override
public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
    if (mLastMarker != null) {
        // Stop task for mLastMarker
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "Info window requested for " + marker);
    mLastMarker = marker;
    return null; // Returning null will load the default InfoWindow
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use setOnMapClickListener on the map and within the onMapClick method you could check whether the task is still running and if yes, end the task.